# Use workflow to delete or amend list items

Tags: list, workflow, delete

I have a holiday booking system that creates list items showing the name and dates of holiday for employees. After management approval, the requests sit in a list called "Holiday Requests". They are also added to a calendar called "Holiday Calendar".

What I need to do is create a cancellation / amendment system if possible. The above request system uses a workflow to gain holiday approval and populate the calendar, so I was hoping I could use a workflow to cancel / amend approved bookings too.

What I need them to be able to do is (ideally!) put a tick next to the holiday to be cancelled, then have a button to cancel the holiday (which should trigger off an authorisation process again), then remove the holiday from the "Holiday Requests" list and also from the "Holiday Calendar".
Similar for the amendment, except allow the dates to be changed rather than removing the booking, then go through the authorisation process again.

Oh, all this would need to be done through SPD2010 if possible too, I don't have Infopath or anything...